# Error Payment Method braintree credit card

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, magento2.2.6, braintree

I have a error in my website https://kiraliving.com

[image]

I did the testing by environment `sandbox credit card` by `paypal` testing and it works perfectly but when I put it live production it keeps thinking and frozen Edit. I don't know why I am looking the error for one week and nothing

I Need you help

Regards,

Felix Lung

Answer (score 1):

As I checked your site, you got the following error in checkout page. You can also view on your console as well.

> Uncaught Error: Braintree API Client Misconfigured: clientToken
>   required.

One of the possible cause of this issue is using of incorrect API keys in magento configuration. Make sure that if you have Braintree configured to be in Sandbox mode in Magento admin, then you have to use Sandbox API keys too.

**I hope this will help**

Answer (score 1):

I have configured the sandbox and the test is working perfectly however live is not working. I try to configure the authorize net however I have other problem the authorize net update the new module without MD5 I did the update the new version but is not working too.

Regards,

Felix